# Problems with relative positioning with css

Tags: html, css-position

I'm trying to build a page with a big div in the middle which "lays" on to other divs on the left and on the right with the code at the end of the question. the three divs should be contained in a further div (called outer) and it's height should be (almost) exactly the height of the div in the middle. Because the height of the div in the middle is not fix this is true forthe outer div as well.

Trying to use relative positioning sets my middle-div below the ones on the left and the right. Setting th etop of the middle div leaves a blank area between the middle div and the lower border of the outer div. Using absolute positioning results in a collapsed outer div.

I would be greatful for any hint or advise.

parascus

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#outer {
   width:300px;
   border:1px solid #000000;
}

#left {
   position:relative;
   display:inline-block;
   float:left;
   margin:3px;
   width:50px;
   border:1px solid #C08080;
}

#right {
   position:relative;
   display:inline-block;
   float:left;
   left:185px;
   margin:3px;
   width:50px;
   border:1px solid #C08080;
   text-align:right;
}

#middle {
    background-color: #FBE6AD;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    left: 50px;
    top: -48;
    width: 200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='outer'>
<div id='left'>DIV Left</div>
<div id='right'>DIV Right</div>
<div id='middle'>
DIV Middle<br>
with an<br>
unknown height<br>
which has effect on the outer height.
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It should look like this:[image: good example]

But I get this:
[image: bad example]

Or this:
[image: worse result]

**The solution (triggered by fenix) was:**

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#outer {
    border:1px solid #000000;
    display:inline-block;
    width:300px;
}

#x {
    display:table-row;
}

#left {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin:3px -5px 0px 3px;
    width:50px;
    border:1px solid #C08080;
    padding:0px;
}

#right {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin:3px 3px 0px -5px;
    width:50px;
    border:1px solid #C08080;
    text-align:right;
}

#middle {
    background-color: rgba(250, 220, 200, 0.8);
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 200px;
    margin:3px 0px 6px 0px;
    z-index:10;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='outer'>
<div id='x'>
<div id='left'>DIV Left</div>
<div id='middle'>
DIV Middle<br>
with an<br>
unknown height<br>
which has effect on the outer height.
</div>
<div id='right'>DIV Right</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This ends in:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered a table with three cells in one row?  Not entirely sure what the content will be, but that might be an alternate route?

Would this be on only one page? Or across multiple pages? If across multiple pages then you could utilize a Master page with the relevant styling reflecting ContentPlaceHolders?

Comment: Yeah, that's it. And using negative margins brings me the overlapping of the inner divs. And further more using zindex reduces complexity for exchanging the position of the right and the middle div.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `position:relative` is to set the origin point for absolutely-positioned children elements.

Therefore, only the outer element needs `position:relative`, the inner elements need `position:absolute` (along with `top`, `left` or `bottom`, `right` positioning).

Absolutely-positioned elements are also removed from the layout flow, so `inline-block` and `float` should be removed since it has no layout context.

Give this a try:

```
#outer {
   width:300px;
   border:1px solid #000000;
   position:relative; 
   min-height:200px 
}

#left {
   float:left;
   margin:3px;
   width:50px;
   border:1px solid #C08080;
}

#right {
   float:right;
   left:185px;
   margin:3px;
   width:50px;
   border:1px solid #C08080;
   text-align:right;
}

#middle {
    background-color: #FBE6AD;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    left: 50px;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: That's not the sole purpose of `position: relative`, but within this context I think you're right.

Comment: But this is the wrong direction as if I use absolute positioning the outer div collapses, dosen't it? But that's not what I want. The outer div should have the height of the middle div.

Comment: The outer div will require a fixed dimension using this technique. Combining relative-only positioning with floats and inline-block can be done, but it's a nightmare to work with.

Comment: That's my experience. But I need it because I don't know the height so I can't set a fix height to the outer div

Comment: In that case, a diagram of the desired result may be helpful.

Comment: I've added some CSS. Give it a try.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33935/discussion-between-parascus-and-diodeus)